# Telegram BOT не работает вообще ни с какими прокси

Tags: python-3.x, telebot

Мой код

```
from telebot import TeleBot, apihelper
from requests import get
from random import choice

def get_proxy():
    return {"http":"socks5://"+choice(get("https://www.proxy-list.download/api/v1/get?type=socks5&country=US").content.split(b"\r\n")).decode()}

apihelper.proxy = get_proxy()
bot = TeleBot("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXTOKENXXXXXXXXXXX")
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_text(message):
    if message.text.lower() == "/start":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Help.")
while 1:

    try:
        bot.polling()

    except Exception as error:

        apihelper.proxy = get_proxy()
```

Как можно заметить, при возникновении ошибки, я запрашиваю прокси с сайта, и добавляю новый прокси в apihelper, но это вообще не решает проблему.

Примечание: прокси не работает не только с sosck5, поначалу я пробовал https, потом http, а потом поставил pysocks и пробовал носки.

Ошибка

```
2020-02-13 03:36:56,220 (util.py:65 PollingThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "ConnectionError occurred, args=(ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None)),)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xorke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Users\xorke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 343, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\xorke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 839, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\xorke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 344, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "C:\Users\xorke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 344, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\xorke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 412, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "C:\Users\xorke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 853, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\xorke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1117, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xorke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Users\xorke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Users\xorke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 367, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "C:\Users\xorke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\xorke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Users\xorke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 343, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\xorke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 839, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\xorke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 344, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "C:\Users\xorke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 344, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\xorke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 412, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "C:\Users\xorke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 853, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\xorke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1117, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None))
```

Comment: Помимо ответа на вопрос, хотелось бы попросить совета в целом в плане работоспособности телеграм ботов на территории РФ, что зарекомендовало себя в работе ? Прокси или ВПН или что ?

Comment: Арендовать VPS не в РФ?..

Comment: @sanmai я просто хотел попробовать кое-что написать, неужели для этого уже что-то арендовать нужно

Comment: Что если за 200 рублей, или сколько там стоит простейший VPS в месяц, вы получите сразу решение вашей проблемы? И сразу сможете что-то написать. Почему нельзя просто так, это вопрос сами знаете к кому.

Answer (score 1):

socks5 не может быть http

внесите изменения в функции get_proxy:
return {"http**s**": "socks5**h**://" + choice

я проверил ваш код с изменением на https и socks5h - всё работает